# Assistance with iPhone 5 View Layout

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using a view that needs to be allowed to fit the iPhone 5 screen however I cannot seem to get the layout correct, I have tried this;

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ) 
    {
        if (IS_IPHONE5) {
            NSLog(@"iPhone 5");

            [SelectionPhotoOptionView setFrame:CGRectMake(470, 0, 640, 568)];
            [SelectionButView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 568)];
            [imageViewSelection setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 568)];
            [imageViewPhotoOption setFrame:CGRectMake(-470, 0, 640, 568)];
            ButtonYpos=612;

        } else {

            NSLog(@"iPhone 4 and Lower");

        [SelectionPhotoOptionView setFrame:CGRectMake(470, 0, 320, 480)];
        [SelectionButView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [imageViewSelection setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [imageViewPhotoOption setFrame:CGRectMake(-470, 0, 320, 480)];
        ButtonYpos=412;
    }
```

The top part is wrong, the iPhone 5 is not laid out correct, I wonder if anyone could help me with a neater code example to use?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether your device resolution is iPhone 5 (4 inch) or lower resolution (3.5 inch) using

```
#define IS_IPHONE ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] | [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"])
#define IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( IS_IPHONE && IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 )
```

then you can set frame by replacing your code with below code :

```
if (IS_IPHONE) 
{
            [SelectionPhotoOptionView setFrame:CGRectMake(470, 0, 320, IS_IPHONE_5?568:480)];
            [SelectionButView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, IS_IPHONE_5?568:480)];
            [imageViewSelection setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, IS_IPHONE_5?568:480)];
            [imageViewPhotoOption setFrame:CGRectMake(-470, 0, 320, IS_IPHONE_5?568:480)];
            ButtonYpos=IS_IPHONE_5?612:412;
}
```

**Note :** In case of iPhone5 you have given width as 640 and in iPhone 4 it is 320. While width is same for both devices. So I changed width 320 in both cases.

It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the screen height by doing the following:

```
        screenRect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
        screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
        if( screenHeight == 568){
            NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
         }
        else NSLog (@"iPhone 4s or below");
```

When setting the frame based on the screen size make sure you are figuring in a Nav bar if you have one (default around 40px) and the status bar, which I believe is 10px.

Also the width is still 320px, the OS will auto adjust for retina display.

Answer (score 0):

Just take two .xib for iphone4 and iphne5. its easy, no need to set frame just push proper View/xib.
like ......

//Device  Compatibility

```
    #define g_IS_IPHONE             ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] )
    #define g_IS_IPOD               ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"] )
    #define g_IS_IPAD               ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPad"] )
    #define g_IS_IPHONE_5_SCREEN    [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 1024.0f
    #define g_IS_IPHONE_4_SCREEN    [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 480.0f && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 568.0f
```

When you push then check the screen..

```
    if (g_IS_IPHONE_4_SCREEN) {
            styleDetailObj =[[StyleDetailViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"StyleDetailViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
     }
        else if (g_IS_IPHONE_5_SCREEN){
            styleDetailObj =[[StyleDetailViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"StyleDetailViewController_iPhone5" bundle:nil];
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:styleDetailObj animated:NO];
```